# T-SQL puzzle: query fails when using it as an inline view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Preparation**

```
create table t (x varchar(18))

insert into t (x) values ('8003372602728'), ('a')
```

Query #1:

```
select cast(x as bigint) y 
from t 
where isnumeric(x) = 1 and cast(x as bigint) > 100
```

Result for query #1:

```
y
--------------------
8003372602728

(1 row affected)
```

Query #2:

```
select * 
from
    (select cast(x as bigint) y 
     from t 
     where isnumeric(x) = 1 and cast(x as bigint) > 100) a
where y is not null
```

Result for query #2:

```
y
--------------------
8003372602728
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

What is the reason of the error in the result for query #2?

Comment: SQL doesn't execute a `WHERE` in the order you write them, it could easily try to pass `cast(x as bigint)>100` before `isnumeric(x)=1`. Just use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST` anyway, it's a far better function over `ISNUMERIC`.

Comment: Trying to `CAST` a column that knowingly has `VARCHAR` values in it is a bad idea.  Plus I don't really understand what the `where y is not null` clause it meant to do.  However if you're stuck with things as they are, you could always select out the rows that you want to `CAST` into another table, then do whatever manipulation you need to there.

Comment: @WAMLeslie The 'where y is not null' is only for demonstrating the error. If I don't give any 'where' condition then query #2 also works without error! This is the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note the difference between these queries:

```
select cast(x as bigint) y 
from t 
where isnumeric(x) = 1
  and cast(x as bigint) > 100;

select cast(x as bigint) y 
from t 
where cast(x as bigint) > 100
  and isnumeric(x) = 1;
```

The first one works and the second fails with the conversion error. The first one works because isnumeric is evaluated first and only numeric values are evaluated. With the second the query is evaluating: `CAST(x as bigint)` first. In theory, neither query should work because filters are not guaranteed to be evaluated in any specific order.

Next, this works:

```
select * 
from
    (select cast(x as bigint) y 
     from t 
     where isnumeric(x) = 1 and cast(x as bigint) > 100) a
----WHERE a.y > 100
```

... But, once you uncomment the WHERE clause it fails. This is because the WHERE clause on the Outer query is evaluating x before determining if ISNUMERIC is true.

This works:

```
select * 
from
    (select cast(x as bigint) y 
     from t 
     where isnumeric(x) = 1 and cast(x as bigint) > 100) a
    WHERE isnumeric(a.y) = 1
```

But, again, when I change the outer query to include a filter for y > 100...

```
select * 
from
    ( select cast(x as bigint) y 
      from t 
      where isnumeric(x) = 1 and cast(x as bigint) > 100) a
    WHERE isnumeric(a.y) = 1 and CAST(a.y AS bigint) > 100
```

It fails. Why? Because order of evaluation is not guaranteed.

TRY_CAST solves two problems:

First, isnumeric is a proprietary legacy function which does not do what most people think. isnumeric thinks all this is numeric:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('.'), ISNUMERIC('$'), ISNUMERIC('-'), ISNUMERIC('+'), ISNUMERIC('$+.');
```

Second, it solves the order of evaluation issue. This query works:

```
select * 
from
    (select TRY_CAST(x as bigint) y 
     from t 
     where TRY_CAST(x AS bigint) IS NOT NULL ) a
WHERE y > 100; -- Implies that it's NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 This is the key: _"order of evaluation is not guaranteed"_. The optimizer can chose to evaluate `cast(x as bigint)` before `isnumeric(x) = 1` for seemingly arbitrary reasons, so the query logic should not rely on that order (and can instead rely on `TRY_CAST` as you suggested). Good job.